# Cut a stroke into pieces in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, stroke

I have drawn the stroke or border, that is without the fill set, of a star with the star tool. Now I want to cut the star stroke into several pieces. I tried to use the eraser tool but it will add stroke lines rather than only cut the stroke. I have no idea how to do this. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

1. Select the star shape and click *Path > Object to Path*
2. Add nodes by double clicking using the *Edit Paths by Nodes Tool*, and/or select a node/nodes where you want to cut.
3. In the tool bar along the top, hit the *Break Path at Selected Nodes* icon.
4. Click *Path > Break Apart*
5. Select the path you just cut, and move it away from the star.

[image]

Another method is to draw an open path over the star, where you want to cut it, then select both star and path, and click *Path > Cut Path*

[image]

Then you can move both parts of the star apart

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Okay, that seems cumbersome. So there is no way to just cut it along some path or so? Also, how do I add a node? I found that when selecting a path segment I can add a node exactly in the middle of the math by clicking on the add node button. But I want other cutting points then this. Is that possible?

Comment: @Daniel OK, I added another method that might suit you better.  Also forgot to say to add nodes just double click with the Edit Nodes by Paths tool.

Comment: "Cut path" didn't do this for me, but "division" did!